# is it passible to save image from link to ftp server directly using python

Tags: python, ftp

i wonder if it possible to save image from link to ftp server directly using python without download them to laptop then upload them to ftp , i tried this way using ftplib and requests but did not work ,and throw this error ,

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
i tried encoding="utf8" and error ignore options but did not work

```
import requests

from ftplib import FTP as tp


url = "https://im0-tub-com.yandex.net/i?id=5fda7c40cfa53d048d169908bbbd7cb6&n=13"

rq =  requests.get(url).content

ftp = tp('host','username','password)
ftp.cwd("www")
    
with open(rq,'rb')  as f:
    ftp.storbinary("STOR "+"name.webp",f)
    ftp.quit()
```

Comment: If it would work this code would download the file anyway (to memory) before uploading to FTP. This can't be avoided.

Comment: tnx man u saved my time @Martin Prikryl

Answer (score 0):

thank to Martin Prikryl , i was able to solve it by edit few things in my code to

```
import requests

from ftplib import FTP as tp


url = "https://im0-tub-com.yandex.net/i?id=5fda7c40cfa53d048d169908bbbd7cb6&n=13"

rq =  requests.get(url , stream=True).raw

ftp = tp('host','username','password)
ftp.cwd("www")
    
ftp.storbinary("STOR "+"name.webp",rq)
ftp.quit()
```